# Last version of Google ANGLE that supports 32-bit on Windows

Tags: winapi, opengl-es, google-angle

I'm using Google's ANGLE so I can use OpenGL ES properly on Windows. I really want it to work on the 32-bit version of Windows so I can support as many PCs as possible. Try as I may, I cannot convince the current version of ANGLE to do it. I'm thus under the impression that Google stopped support for 32-bit Windows when they did the same for Chromium.

I do know that old versions of ANGLE do work quite well for converting ES3.1 to D3D. I'd like to find the latest version that did so for 32-bit. Does anyone know what version it was and where to find it?

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to convince the current version of ANGLE to actually compile 32-bit libraries, that would be even better. I've had no luck with this myself.

Comment: Maybe you could see what the last version of Chromium that supported 32-bit is, and look at its source to find out what version of ANGLE it used?

Comment: That would likely be an older version of ANGLE than necessary, as it's unlikely they stopped 32-bit support in ANGLE the same day. Also, although I can find out when they announced it, I don't know the exact last build of 32-bit Chromium (on Windows). Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

OK, as of July 2021, it appears I can now compile ANGLE in 32-bit mode again. I can't find any corroborating information from Google, but I suspect they still wish to support 32-bit ANGLE despite no 32-bit Chrome and I was unlucky with the 2020 version I was using. If so, I'm ecstatic about their decision, as the old version I previously was using started to throw DirectX deprecation warnings.